# Spring Boot DevTools initialization errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Wanted to experiment with [Spring Boot DevTools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) (library for hot reloading), but encountered some issues after including it in our project.
Beans with `@Lazy` fields were raising `BeanCreationException`:

> Error creating bean with name 'project.specific.Bean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class project.specific.Factory]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

*project.specific.Bean* looks like this

```
@Component
public class Bean ... {
    ...
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private Factory factory;
    ...
}
```

I tried DevTools with Spring Boot [Athens](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/spring-io-platform-athens-release) and [Brussels](https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/21/spring-io-platform-brussels-release) with the same results.

After simply removing `@Lazy` there was also some problem with `@Repository`, which I just replaced with `@Component` (tried this only with Athens).

After that there was also this really strange problem:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: project.specific.Product cannot be cast to project.specific.Product

Obviously I don't want to remove `@Lazy` and replace `@Repository` with `@Component`, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it caused by spring dev tool's restart classloader.
refer to document of [Automatic restart](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-spring-boot-restart-vs-reload)

> The restart technology provided by Spring Boot works by using two
>   classloaders. Classes that don’t change (for example, those from
>   third-party jars) are loaded into a base classloader. Classes that
>   you’re actively developing are loaded into a restart classloader.

it mean, some of your classes were loaded by different classloaders (restart classloader or base classloader).
and if class was loaded by different classloader , it recognize as different class(bean).

that is why your project failed to autowire beans and occurred ClassCastException even between same classes.

and workaround is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload)

you can choice which classloader will load your classes explicitly by spring-devtools.properties.

Comment: You mean I'll need to exclude some classes/libraries so that they would be loaded by "base" classloader? But the problems I had with `@Lazy` and `@Repository` came from jars, which already should be excluded.